# Is the struct destructor called if the variable is being returned by a function/operator?

Tags: c++, struct, destructor

Suppose we have a **struct** named **A** declared this way:

```
struct A{
  ~A(){
     cout << "destructor called" << endl;
  }
}
```

and a main:

```
A create(){
  A variableToReturn;
  return variableToReturn;
}
int main() {
  A var1 = create();
  return 0;
}
```

is the destructor called even though we returned the variable from a function and so is the variable in main **var1** defined or not?
Same question arise if we return the variable from an operator such as:

```
A var1 = var2 + var3;
```

Comment: Lookup RVO and NVRO.

Comment: Your code is fine, the compiler will take care of destroying and creating objects here.

Comment: Read a good C++ programming book, then [some C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), then [n3337](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or something newer. Be aware of the [rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html). Provide some [mre] in your next question

Comment: Overloaded operators are normal functions, but with peculiar names.